# Searching Vector of Struct

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct, iterator, find

I have a struct like this:

```
struct Stock{
    int id;
    string title;
    string colour;
    string size;
    int quantity;
    float cost;
}
```

Vector

```
vector<Stock> all_data;
```

Now I want to search for a specific stock in the **all_data** vector by the ID. How can I do this?

Comment: You loop through the vector, checking each `Stock` inside to see if it's the right one.

Comment: Apart from the straightforward answer of having an if statement in a loop, also take a look at [this So post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517991/search-a-vector-of-objects-by-object-attribute)

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59177607/edit) the question and put the actual struct in it. `id` is _not_ a private member of `Stock` as the question now stands - which you only mention in a comment to one of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(auto data : all_data){
    if(data.id == id)
        std::cout << "Found";
}
```

Comment: @user11453590 You should add this to your question. BUT,  the `struct` keyword in C++ means that (by default) all members of the struct are public. So something is clearly missing from your question

Comment: @user11453590 If `id` is a private member of `Stock`, then the `Stock` definition you showed us is different from the actual one. Please, do not waste our time and write your question more carefully using your actual code/case.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica I agree, but please be friendlier. The user is clearly learning, it doesn't mean that they are careless. You are not helping either

Comment: @kyriakosSt asking to fix error in code that does not have the error is careless, what else?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 May be simply due to lack of knowledge, but even so, saying to a novice user (both in SO and evidently in programming) that they waste our time is not the way to go.

Comment: @kyriakosSt please dont turn everything into a discussion about friendlyness / welcomingness. Not showing the code that matches the error is wasting time and it has to be allowed to say this (also to a new user)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I respectfully disagree for this specific case, but we can have different opinions. Sorry for starting this conversation

Comment: Thanks I solved the issue. Sorry for being unclear and my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard algorithm `std::find_if`. For example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//…

int id = some_value;

auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( all_data ), std::end( all_data ),
                        [=]( const Staock &stocl )
                        {
                            return stock.id == id;
                        } );

if ( it != std::end( all_data ) )
{
    std::cout << it->id << '\n';
}
```

Instead of the lambda you could use the function object `std::equal_to` and `std::bind` provided that you are going to compare the whole objects of the type Stock or if you will declare a corresponding comparison operator.

Here is a demonstrative program that uses a lambda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct Stock{
    int id;
    std::string title;
    std::string colour;
    std::string size;
    int quantity;
    float cost;
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<Stock> all_data =
    {
        { 1, "A" }, { 2, "B" }, { 3, "C" }, { 4, "D" }, { 5, "E" }
    };

    int id = 3;

    auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( all_data ), std::end( all_data ),
                            [=]( const Stock &stock )
                            {
                                return stock.id == id;
                            } );

    if ( it != std::end( all_data ))
    {
        std::cout << it->id << ": " << it->title << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
3: C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
it = std::find_if(all_data.begin(), all_data.end(), std::bind(&all_data::id, _1) == data.id);
```

from `#include <algorithm>`

Or, you can write your own function object

```
struct find_id : std::unary_function<Stock, bool> {
    int id;
    find_id(int id):id(id) { }
    bool operator()(Stock const& m) const {
        return m.id == id;
    }
};

it = std::find_if(alll_data.Stock.begin(), all_data.Stock.end(), 
         find_id(currentStockObject));
```

Modify as needed.

Comment: curiosity: why inherit from `unary_function` ?

Comment: Interesting. `unary_function` was deprecated in C++11 and is supposed to have been removed in C++17, but both `clang++` and `g++` have kept it. https://godbolt.org/z/JgbXDR